# How to disable cache for perticular template file in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, cache, full-page-cache

We have used full page cache but some particular part of section not reflected.
for example, we have a select city in the dropdown but not reflected.
check my site- https://vidyutbazar.com/
A different way to disable it but not work for me.check below code.

> Path =
>   frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml
>   Block = Mage_Core_Block_Tem

```
<reference name="Mage_Core_Block_Tem">
  <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action>
  </reference>

<reference name="top.search">
  <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action>
  </reference>

<reference name="top.bar">
  <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml">
    <action method="unsCacheLifetime"></action>
  </block>
  </reference>
```

I need to disable cache for this block.so i use above code in this layout but it is not work for me.Please help me how to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with .htaccess by using code like this:

```
<FilesMatch "path_to_your_file\.phtml$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Source: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/disable-caching-htaccess